# How to set type of method parameters to a alterable object in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, iterable

How to create a method like following with iterable specific object input in python:

In Java we can create it like below:

```java
abstract public ArrayList<Device> returnDevices(ArrayList<Object> Device){
   ...
}
```

In python I want to create a model like following:

```py
class OptionModel:
    def __init__(
            self,
            option: str = None,
    ) -> None:
        self.__option = option

    @property
    def option(self):
        return self.__option

    @option.setter
    def option(self, value):
        self.__option = value
```

And in another class i want to get a list of **OptionModel** object as below:

```py
class Command:
    def __init__(
            self,
            options: List[OptionModel] = None,
    ) -> None:
        self.__options = options
    
    @property
    def options(self) -> List[OptionModel]:
        return self.__options

    @options.setter
    def options(self, value: List[OptionModel]):
        self.__options = value
```

And when for loop on **Options**_ get the OptionModel in my IDE:

```py
    def print_summery(self):
        for option in self.options:
            print("  {}  {}\t\t{}".format(option.option, option.alias, option.brief))
```

Comment: Does "alterable" mean an object of any type? You can just specify `-> List` without specifying the contents type. Or there is a generic `object` type in python.
Also, it's not Java. putting setters and getters on everything is not a part of Python style.

Comment: What's your question?  It looks like your code already does the thing you're describing -- the one bug I see is that your `Command` class should be initializing `self.__options` to `options or []` since it looks like your other functions expect it to be a list.  Using "strict optional" checking in `mypy` will catch things like this!